# sqlite3.dylib: illegal multi-threaded access to database connection

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iOS app that uses `sqlite3` and I'm facing issues with multi-threading crashing the app with the `illegal multi-threaded access to database connection` message. Of course, it's because I'm using multi-threading; the problem is, my sqlite3 instance is configured to use multi-thread:

```
sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD);
```

Even though I'm using multi-threading (sqlite3 build was also compiled with the multi-threading flag), it causes my app to crash when multiple threads write or read the database simultaneously.

Crash report

```
Application Specific Information:
BUG IN CLIENT OF sqlite3.dylib: illegal multi-threaded access to database connection

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001823ed2fc
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  12

Thread 12 Crashed:

0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001823ed2fc sqlite3MutexMisuseAssert + 144 (sqlite3.c:23788)
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001823ed2ec sqlite3MutexMisuseAssert + 128 (once.h:84)
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018235248c sqlite3LockAndPrepare + 320 (sqlite3.c:23801)
3   MyCodeCall.m ...........
```

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and I couldn't find any reference to this on google unfortunately.

**UPDATE**

```
+(sqlite3*) getInstance {
  if (instance == NULL) {
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD);
    sqlite3_initialize();

    NSLog(@"isThreadSafe %d", sqlite3_threadsafe());

    const char *path = [@"./path/to/db/db.sqlite" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (sqlite3_open_v2(path, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
      NSLog(@"Database opening failed!");
    }
  }

  return instance;
}
```

Comment: Did you open the database using the `SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX` flag as part of the `sqlite3_open_v2` call?

Comment: @rmaddy no, I'm using the sqlite3 api `sqlite3_open`.

Comment: You really should use `sqlite3_open_v2`. Always use the newer APIs.

Comment: @rmaddy I've changed to `sqlite3_open_v2` but still, no difference made same exceptions crashed the app. I've updated the question with the db helper method.

Comment: So adding `| SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX` to the other open flags doesn't help?

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 in an Objective-C app and I do not call `sqlite3_shutdown`, `sqlite3_config`, or `sqlite3_initialize`. Nor do I specify anything other than `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` when opening a database and I have no issues using the connection across multiple threads.

Comment: @rmaddy I think `NOMUTEX` isn't working because actually there's multiple threads using the same connection simultaneously, which is an issue with multithreading by it self; therefore, you have to use `FULLMUTEX` for `SERIALIZED` threading mode (which is not as ideal). I think the best option is opening a new connection each thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I solved the problem by using `SERIALIZED` in `FULL_MUTEX` mode; I provided an answer but feel free to provide yours if you have a more elaborated one. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out that `SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD` mode works well on a multi-threading environment as long as you don't use the same connection simultaneously; which happen to be the exact scenario that I had. Therefore, to solve this issue you can either open a new connection for each thread or use `SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED` in full mutex mode using `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` flag to open the connection.

The helper method ended up like so:

```
+(sqlite3*) getInstance {
  if (instance == NULL) {
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
    sqlite3_initialize();

    NSLog(@"isThreadSafe %d", sqlite3_threadsafe());

    const char *path = [@"./path/to/db/db.sqlite" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (sqlite3_open_v2(path, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
      NSLog(@"Database opening failed!");
    }
  }

  return instance;
}
```

Comment: for me not exists `sqlite3_config`, I also have the same problem.

Comment: @Augusto It did not exist for me either, but just adding `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` seems to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8):

In case of any one faced this problem in Swift. Solution will be:

```
let dbName = "first.db"
static let shared = DatabaseManger()
var db: OpaquePointer?


private init(){
    print("singletone initialized")
    sqlite3_shutdown();
    let dbPath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent(dbName)
    if sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("Successfully opened database connection at \(dbPath.path)")
    }
    else {
        print("unable to open database connection")
    }
}
```

This code tested in swift version 4.0 and 4.2

Comment: what is the use for `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`?

Comment: @AppDeveloper, SQLITE_TRANSIENT has nothing to do it this init method, it was required to insert some blob value, removing from answer

Answer (score 5):

Use please SQLite Shared-Cache Mode
https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html

sqlite3_open_v2(path.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE, nil) != SQLITE_OK

SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE

Reliable 100%  :)

Answer (score 3):

From `https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html`

> SQLite supports three different threading modes:
>
> Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is
>   unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.
>
> Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads provided that no single database connection is used
>   simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads with no restriction.

In iOS，SQLite default threading mode was `SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX`(equal to Multi-thread),which was not safe when multiple threads write or read the database simultaneously use one connection.
Change threading mode to serialized may helpful for you.You can change threading mode use `sqlite3_config()` or `sqlite3_open_v2()`.