# iOS App Crashing on launch when users updated to iOS 13.6

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS app in the store written in Swift that seemed to be working fine for the last 2 years. However, in the recent past, users reported that the app was crashing after they updated to iOS 13.5.1.

During this time, several other notable apps like Spotify, Pinterest, Tiktok ad Instagram were crashing as well due to some Facebook SDK bug which they claimed to have fixed.

None the less, I removed the Facebook SDK from the app and resubmitted the app as an update hoping to fix this issue.

Users have installed the new updated and some users have even updated to iOS 13.6. A few users have reported crashes again on app launch.

The problem is I am unable to reproduce the crash on a device or a simulator.

I was wondering and hoping someone ran into this issue and has any ideas on how to resolve this ?

**Edit**

Here are the crash logs I see from the app store after the advice from Benjamin below: https://pastebin.com/BPbn77T8 - when I click open in project: http://prntscr.com/tpnxp1 - it leads me to this line of code in the project

```
let classification  = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "classification") as! String
```

I know it is not a lot of code to work with but this issue never occurred before the latest iOS 13.4 update that I know off.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the crash logs in Xcode (Window -> Organizer -> Crashes)?

Comment: @BenjaminWen - the thing is the crash does not occur at my end. It is just reported by a user who has downloaded my app. I can find very limited info on this like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5Xa_ZS9l08 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vypjGOw11-U

Comment: some crash logs may be automatically sent to App Store thus accessible in Xcode. If there is no logs, then it is very hard to find the cause.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminWen - did not know this could be done before. I have updated my question with more information .. maybe you have some ideas ? Much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198831/sqlite3-dylib-illegal-multi-threaded-access-to-database-connection Check out this link. The crash shares many things in common with this one.

Comment: Using `as !` is a recipe for a crash if something goes wrong - Can you code more defensively and handle the decode via a conditional cast?

Comment: Thanks for your input @Paulw11 and Benjamin .. appreciate the advice and I will add the conditional casts. The one thing that confuses me though is why this would crash on one device or instance and not on another instance with the exact same data. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this - where a user reports a crash that you cannot replicate locally - are why remote logging is important.

The best way to solve an issue like this is to enable remote logging/crash reporting BEFORE the issue arises. That way you have logs and stack traces that can help you see what caused the crash.

For more info, take a look at services like Google Crashlytics, Datadog, or New Relic. I’m not advocating for any. There are many services out there. But those are some common examples.